# Unable to apply my own designed styles for the TitleBar's background and text

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the two styles defined in the xml code below; however, I defined them in the styles.xml but I don't know how to apply them as well as where to implement them? in the layout.xml, in the  manifest.xml or in the java file?

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FF4444</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/DARKRED</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different scope you can apply your style too. For example, in your manifest, in your application tag, there is a theme attribute. So you do can something like this:

```
    <application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" >
```